# Multiple Reactives with ggplot, check boxes and date range

Tags: r, dataframe, input, ggplot2, shiny

I'm using Shiny and ShinyDashboard and I'm trying to plot a geom_bar where the x-value is reacting to a date range and the fill is reacting to the selected projects using checkboxGroupInput. My date range was working perfectly when I simply ran the date_data() function in my ggplot data =, but once i tried subsetting with project_data(), my code started returning something weird: depending on how I check/uncheck the boxes, random bars and fills will be showing up, like in the picture provided (link below), as opposed to what i want... here is my code

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
skin = "purple",
dashboardHeader(title = '[enter image description here][1]Dashboard'),
dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(
  menuItem('Dashboard', tabName = 'dashboard', icon = icon('dashboard')),

  menuItem(
    dateRangeInput('date_range', label = "Date Range",format = "mm/dd/yyyy", start = Sys.Date()-17, end = Sys.Date()+17, startview = "month", weekstart = 0, separator = " to ", width = 200)
  ),

  menuItem(
    checkboxGroupInput('project_name', label = "Project", choices = c(unique(allocated$Project)), selected = allocated$Project)
  )
)
),
dashboardBody(
tags$head(
  tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")
),

fluidRow(
  box(plotOutput("plot1", width = 1000, height = 500))
),

fluidRow(
  box(plotOutput("plot2", width = 1000, height = 500))
)
)
)



server <- function(input, output) {

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
date_data <- reactive({
  subset(allocated, variable >= input$date_range[1] & variable <= input$date_range[2])})
project_data <- reactive({subset(date_data(), Project == input$project_name)})

ggplot(data = project_data(), aes(x = variable, y = value, alpha = time, fill = Project)) + 
geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + scale_x_date(name = 'Load Date', breaks = allocated$variable, date_labels =  "%m/%d")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in how you are subsetting `date_data()` within `project_data()`. Using `Project == input$project_name`, searches for places in the data.frame where `Project` is *exactly equal* to the input vector coming from the `checkboxGroupInput`, `input$project_name`.

Instead, use `match()` to return the indices where individual values in `input$project_name` match up with individual values in the `Project` vector.

Specifically, replace the code currently defining `project_data()` with the following line:

`date_data()[match(input$project_name, date_data()$Project), ]`

Comment: Thank you @thisislammers! I actually figured it out too about an hour after I posted this, using Project %in% input$project_name.. do you know if your way is more efficient??

Comment: @Naji, I doubt there's much difference in efficiency, as `match(x, y)` is the same as using `which(x %in% y)`. If anything, your way may be slightly more efficient, but it's really just a matter of preference.